# if $ab=cd$ then $a+b+c+d $ is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

Let $a,b,c,d$ be natural numbers with $ab=cd$.
Prove that $a+b+c+d$ is composite.
I have my own solution for this (As posted) and i want to see if there is any other good proofs.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: I vote against closing this question.

Comment: Let the OP respond before *closing* the question. The question seems pretty good.

Comment: I already know the answer but it is kinda hard. SO i posted it in here to see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: @CODE: It will be very good of you if you post the answer you know. We can indeed think of another way out.

Comment: I, too, find this question interesting. Nevertheless I downvoted it for the way it was asked: No context was given, no own effort is shown and only in the comments it turns out it was merely asked to see if someone will come up with a better solution and that the questioner already has solutions. So my read on it is that it’s basically a test to see whether other people are as clever as the questioner which I find rude. But maybe I misinterpret this? At the very least, I think you, CODE, should add your intentions to the question.

Comment: Here you are! I posted one of my own answers :)

Comment: Note this does not work if you include 0 in the natural numbers.  (Obvious counterexample: a = 0, b=3, c=0, d=4, so ab = cd = 0, but a+b+c+d=7 which is prime).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$ab=cd$ implies $a=xy, b=zt, c=xz, d=yt$ for some integers $x,y,z,t$. Hence
$$
a+b+c+d=(x+t)(y+z).
$$

Comment: This may be nitpicking, but $2 \cdot 3 = 3 \cdot 2$ does not imply $2 = xy$.

Comment: @nightcracker: Sorry, I didn't understand. Do you consider the case $a=d=2, b=c=3$?

Comment: @nightcracker: $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=3$, $d=2$, $x=1$, $y=2$, $z=3$, $t=1$ works.

Comment: Of course, pesky $1$ :D Nevermind.

Comment: @nightcracker: Still this answer is more that a bit sketchy, for the construction of $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: How do we construct x, y, z, t? I don't find it obvious that there are integers like that.

Comment: @fgrieu The unjustified claim is sometimes called the [Four Number Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835192/242).  It is an easy consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations of integers). There are many closely related formulations of such factorization refinements, e.g. see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 15):

From $ab=cd$ you have $$(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=(c+d)^2-(c-d)^2\Rightarrow(a+b)^2-(c+d)^2=(a-b)^2-(c-d)^2$$ Hence we have $$(a+b+c+d)(a+b-c-d)=(a-b+c-d)(a-b-c+d)$$ Now note that $|a+b+c+d|>|a-b+c-d|$ and $|a-b-c+d|$. If $(a+b+c+d)$ was prime then it must divide one of $(a-b+c-d)$ or $(a-b-c+d)$, which is not possible.

Comment: +1. Beautiful. Though this argument won't work (as it is) for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: It's not hard to show a slightly simpler identity: $a(a+b+c+d)=(a+c)(a+d)$, with the result following from there by a similar size argument.

Comment: @user17762 It's not clear to me what is wrong with the proof in your eyes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think he was getting at the fact that one (or both) of $a-b+c-d$ or $a-b-c+d$ may be $0$, in which case $a+b+c+d$ would divide it even if it were prime. Of course, in that case $a,b$ is the same as $c,d$ modulo reordering, so the sum is divisible by 2 and the result still holds.

Comment: Yeah, if $a+b-c-d=0$ then $a+b+c+d=2(a+b)$ is not prime. @jerry

Answer (score 6):

From $ab=cd$, We may assume $a=\frac{cd}{b}$. So $M=a+b+c+d = \frac{cd}{b}+b+c+d = \frac{(b+c)(b+d)}{b}$ and so $bM=(b+c)(b+d)$ and $M|(b+c)(b+d)$. We assume that $M$ is not composite, so it is prime. Now we may know that either $b+c$ or $b+d$ is divisible by $M$. So $M\leq b+c$ or $M\leq b+d$ which both result in contradiction because $M=a+b+c+d > b+c$ or $b+d$. So our assumption was wrong and $M$ is a composite number.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Plug $a=\frac{cd}{b}$ into the sum to get

$$\frac{(b+c)(b+d)}{b}$$

which cannot be prime.

Comment: Why can you assume that?

Comment: It may not be correct if $b+d$ was not divisible by $b$.

Comment: @CODE: See the edit.

Comment: Dear @Thomas Andrews: I added the word *hint* into the body.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: thanks, edited!

Answer (score 2):

Call the sum $\,f.\ $ Then $\ af = a^2 + \!\overbrace{ab}^{\Large cd}\!+ac+ad = \overbrace{(a+c)}^{\large M}\,\overbrace{(a+d)}^{\large N}\,$

[By unique factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1137305/242) $\, a\mid MN\,\Rightarrow\,a = mn,\,\ m\mid M,\, n\mid N,\,$ thus

$\ f = \dfrac{MN}a = \dfrac{M}m\dfrac{N}n.\ $ Each factor is $>1\,$ by  $\,m,n \le a < M,N$.

Comment: Imported from a [deleted question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227076/if-ab-cd-then-a2-b2-c2-d2-is-composite#comment2497487_1227076), where $\,f = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2,\,$ so $\,a^2f = (a^2+c^2)(a^2+d^2)\,$ so the same proof as above works.

Answer (score 2):

Write $p=a+b+c+d$ and say $p$ is prime. Then we have $$ab=c(p-a-b-c)$$ so $$(a+c)(b+c) = cp$$
which means that $$p\mid a+c\;\;\;\;{\rm or}\;\;\;\;p\mid b+c$$
in 1st case we get $p=a+b+c+d\leq a+c$ a contradiction. The same contradiction we get in the second case. So $p$ must be composite.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$ab$ has to have *at least* $3$ prime factors.(If $a,b,c,d$ are distinct naturals)

$ab=p_1p_2p_3\dots p_n=cd$

$a=p_1p_2 \dots p_j$

$b=p_{j+1} \dots p_n$

$c=p_kp_{k+1} \dots p_l$

$d=p_1p_2 \dots p_{k-1}p_{l+1}p_{l+2} \dots p_n$

Comment: Who says they have to be distinct? Take, for example, $a=b=2, c=4, d=1$.

Comment: None says they have to be distinct. You have a more general case if you distinct numbers.

Answer (score -1):

$ab=cd$ (with $a, b, c, d$ different from zero otherwise the statement is trivial) implies that 
$$
\frac{a}{c}=\frac{d}{b}=k
$$
Hence $a=ck$ and $d=bk$. Plugging these two last equations into $a+b+c+d$
one finds:
$$
a+b+c+d=ck+b+c+bk=k(b+c)+(b+c)=(k+1)(b+c)
$$

This seems the simplest solution to me but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Yes, you missed that $k$ need be an integer so $k+1$ need not be an integer factor of th sum.