# Divisor of a product of integers is a product of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I read this recently on the web and can't manage to understand it. Not homework -- I haven't done math homework for years.

If $d\mid ab$ then $d=d_1 d_2$, that $d_1\mid a$, that $d_2\mid b$ and, further, if $(a,b)=1$ then $(d_1,d_2)=1$.

I know it's the same question... if $a = a_1 a_2 ... a_n$, why can't $d$ divide some $a_i$ and only $a_i$?

Comment: It can, but then the other part of $d$ is just 1. Which satisfies $(d1,1)=1$ automatically

Comment: Look at an example. d=6,a=4,b=3

Comment: And another example: $d=6$, $a=12$, $b=5$.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513520/242).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**  $ $ by $\, d\mid j,k\!\!\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm U\!\!}\iff} d\mid (j,k)\,$ [[gcd Universal property]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242), and   $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{DL} =$  [gcd Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)

$\,\ d\mid ab\iff d\mid ab,db\!\! \color{#c00}{\overset{\rm U\!\!}\iff} d\mid (ad,db)\overset{\color{#0a0}{\rm D\,L}} = (a,d)b \iff \color{#90f}{d/(a,d)\mid b}$

Hence we conclude $\ d\, =\, (a,d)\, \dfrac{d}{(a,d)}  \ $ where $\ (a,d)\mid a,\ $ and $\ \color{#90f}{\dfrac{d}{(a,d)}\mid b},\ $ as sought.

It works fine if $\ d\mid a,\,$ then $\,(a,d)=d\ $ so $\,d/(a,d) = 1,\,$ so $\,d = d\cdot 1\,$ where $\,d\mid a,\ 1\mid b$.

**Generalization** $ $ The property that is considered in your question may be considered to be a generalization of the prime divisor property from atoms (irreducibles) $\,p\,$ to composites $\,c.\,$

**Prime Divisor Property**  $\quad p\ |\ a\:b\ \Rightarrow\ p\:|\:a\ $ or $\ p\:|\:b\ \ $ [= Euclid's Lemma in $\Bbb Z$]

**Primal Divisor Property**  $\ \ \: c\ |\ a\:b\ \Rightarrow\ c_1\, |\: a\:,\: $ $\ c_2\:|\:b,\ \ c = c_1\:c_2\ $

One easily checks that atoms are  primal $\Leftrightarrow$ prime. This leads to various "refinement" views of unique factorizations, e.g. via [Schreier refinement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/basic-divisibility-fact/6657#6657) and [Riesz interpolation,](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ehb3/publ/euk-2.pdf) the Euclid-Euler [Four Number Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835192/242) (aka [Vierzahlensatz](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ehb3/publ/euk-1.pdf)), etc, which prove more natural in noncommutative rings - see  Paul Cohn's 1973 Monthly survey [Unique Factorization Domains.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319253)

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious about the second item in the equivalence chain in your hint...

Comment: @psoft I elaborated on that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand the notation d|x,y. d divides both x and y?

Comment: @psoft Yes $\ d\mid x,y\,$ means $\,d\mid x,\ d\mid y\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque. I can follow the proof up to the part where you have $d|(a,d)b$ then you divide $d$ by $(a,d)$. Is this division possible in any given gcd domain? wouldn't you have to prove that $(a,d)$ is a unit first?

Comment: @Mikel $\,0\neq c:=(a,d)\mid d,\,$ so we can cancel $\,c\,$ from $\,d\mid cb\,$ yielding $\,d/c\mid \,b\,$ by [divisibility cancellation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3590567/242) (recall elements $\neq 0$ in an integral domain are *cancellable* - the prior linked post shows how  such cancellation extends from equations to divisibility relations). $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque. I can see this when we have $ac=ab \Rightarrow c=b$. However, when $a$ is not explicitly on say the right hand side wouldn't you need $a$ to have an inverse in order to get $c/a$?

Comment: @Mikel $\,c\mid d\,\Rightarrow\, cx = d\,$ has a root $\,x,\,$ which is *unique*: 
 $\,cx = d = cx'\!\Rightarrow x=x'\,$ by cancelling $\,c\neq 0.\,$ This unique quotient $\,x\,$ is denoted $\,d/c,\ $ so $\ c\mid d\,\Rightarrow\, d = (d/c)c\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Ahh I see, I wasn't getting the notation. Thanks for the help!!