# Quadratic residue modulo $p$ if quadratic residue module $p^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to prove this statement. I've already checked here in StackExchange but I can only find the proof of the converse.

In Wikipedia, it is stated: "A number $a$ relatively prime to an odd prime $p$ is a residue modulo any power of $p$ if and only if it is a residue modulo $p$", and I want to prove the only if part.

This problem appeared to me when I wanted to solve the following problem:

Check that the only solutions, up to congruence, of $X^2 \equiv 25 $ (mod $p^k)$, for any $k$ and for any prime $p \neq 2$, $5$, are $X \equiv \pm 5 $  (mod $p^k)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This result (its generallization, to be precise) is called Hensel's lemma. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but at the time this exercise was proposed to me, I hadn't already seen that Lemma, it only comes afterwards, so I shall not use it here, there has to be another way.

Comment: The title and the body say you want to prove different implications. I assume the body is correct.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I already corrected the body, clearly it was not correct due to my previous explanation.

Comment: OK, you can prove it in this particular case. Suppose we know that there is solution $x\equiv a\pmod {p^k}$ and we want to build solution modulo $p^{k+1}$. Consider $x_0\equiv a+tp^k$ and try to find $t$ such that $x_0$ is a solution modulo $p^{k+1}$.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I corrected a few moments earlier that that is not the implication that I want to prove.

Comment: If $a \equiv b^2 \pmod{p^k}$, you can just reduce both sides mod $p$ and get $\overline{a} \equiv \overline{b}^2 \pmod{p}$, where $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ are the reductions mod $p$. More formally, there is the reduction homomorphism $\pi: \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ taking an element to its reduction mod $p$. If $a = b^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$, then $\pi(a) = \pi(b^2) = \pi(b)^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If you are trying to prove the direction indicated in the question, note that if $x\equiv a^2\mod{p^k}$, then $x-a^2 = tp^k = tp^{k-1}p$, so that $x\equiv a^2\mod{p}$.

Comment: These last two comments do the job, thank you all !

Comment: @Albert This is a special case of basic divisibility theorems in $\Bbb Z$ (true in any UFD), as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You indicated that the problem

  Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $p$ be a prime other than $2$ or $5$.
  Show that the only solutions, up to congruence, of $x^2 \equiv 25\;(\text{mod}\;p^k)$ are $x \equiv \pm 5\;(\text{mod}\;p^k)$.

is the underlying problem which you are trying to solve.

For the above problem, there is no need to consider quadratic residues.

Instead, we can argue as follows . . .

Suppose $x$ is an integer such that $x^2 \equiv 25\;(\text{mod}\;p^k)$.

Note that $x+5$ and $x-5$ can't both be divisible by $p$, else their difference
$$
(x+5)-(x-5)=10
$$
would be divisible by $p$, contrary to $p\ne 2,5$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
x^2 \equiv 25\;(\text{mod}\;p^k)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p^k{\,\mid\,}x^2-25
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p^k{\,\mid\,}(x+5)(x-5)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}(x+5)(x-5)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}(x+5)\;\text{or}\;p{\,\mid\,}(x-5)\;\text{but not both}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then since $p^k{\,\mid\,}(x+5)(x-5)$ and exactly one of $x+5,x-5$ is divisible by $p$, it follows that exactly one of $x+5,x-5$ is divisible by $p^k$.

Therefore $x \equiv \pm 5\;(\text{mod}\;p^k)$, as was to be shown.

Comment: @Albert The above proof is a special case of basic divisibility theorems in $\Bbb Z$ (true in any UFD), as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the primary (prime power) form of Euclid's Lemma below (put $\,B=x\!+\!5,\,C=x\!-\!5,\,$ so $\,(p,B,C) = (p,B,B\!-\!C) = (p,x\!+\!5,10)=1\,$ by $\,(p,10)=1)$

**Primary Euclid Lemma** $\ \color{#0a0}{(p,B,C)=1},\ p^k\mid BC\Rightarrow p^k\mid B\,$ or $\,p^k\mid C,\ $ for prime $p$

which is the special case $\,a\,$ is primary in a primitive [primal form of Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1137785/242)

**$\rm\color{#0a0}{Primitive}$ Primal Euclid's Lemma** $\ $ If $\,a,B,C\,$ are integers then

$$\begin{align}  &a\mid BC,\ \color{#0a0}{(a,B,C)=1}\\[.2em]
\Longrightarrow \   &a = bc,\qquad\:\! \color{#0a0}{(b,c)=1}\\ &b\mid B,\,c\mid C \end{align}$$

**Proof** $\,\ a = bc,\ b\mid B,\ c\mid C\,$ follows by the link (by gcd laws or $\Bbb Z$ a UFD) and the coprimality is clear: $\ d\mid b,c\,\Rightarrow d\mid B,C,bc\!=\!a\,$ so $\,d\mid\color{#0a0}{(B,C,a)=1}$