# If $a, b, c, d$ are natural numbers, such that, $ab = cd$, prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ is a composite number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> If $a, b, c, d$ are natural numbers, such that, $ab = cd$, prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ is a composite number.

Came across this question while solving an exercise on prime numbers.

Now I found a pretty simple solution to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383394/prove-abcd-is-composite).

(It is not the exact same problem but the method described there in most of the answers can be easily used on this one too.)

But when I was trying to solve this on my own, I took another path.

I noticed that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ is even (and therefore composite) if:

(1) All of $a, b, c, d$ have the same parity (i.e. all are odd or all are even).

(2) Two of them are even and two are odd (say $a, c$ are even and $b, d$ are odd).

So the only case left to worry about is when $a, b, c$ are even and $d$ is odd (wlog).

Example: $26\times 28 = 56\times 13$ ...and... $13^2 + 26^2 + 28^2 + 56^2 = 4765$.

And this is where I'm stuck. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** As pointed out in some if the answers, my initial assumption of the given expression always being divisible by 5 was wrong (I apologise for that). But I'd still like to see if it can proved, in the manner I started out, that the given expression is composite.

Comment: Euler's [4 squares identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity) may be of some help.

Comment: @Answerers *Please* don't post here proofs *different* from the one the OP proposes. Most common proofs are already in the link given in the OP. If you know a new proof then please post it in that linked post - not here.

Comment: $1 \times 0 = 0 \times 1$ and $1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 + 1^2 = 2$ is prime.

Comment: @Essadi $0$ is not considered a natural number here.

Comment: Observe: with $ab=cd$ the cross terms in $(a+b)^2+(c-d)^2$ and $(a-b)^2+(c+d)^2$ cancel, so both of these two-square sums equal $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Answer (score 4):

It's not always divisible by $5$:

$6 \times 6 = 4 \times 9$ but $6^2+6^2+4^2+9^2 = 169$

Comment: Thanks for that. I also had a feeling about it, but I tried about 10 different cases and I got a multiple of 5 every single time. It was a mistake to assume what I did. Thanks for a counter example, but I'd still like to know if there's a way of proving the initial question in the way I started (now that divisibility by 5 is out of the way).

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you found a proof looking at divisibility by a fixed set of primes. Consider for example: $4^2+6^2+24^2+1^2 = 17\times 37$, $6^2+10^2+4^2+15^2 = 13\times 29$, $10^2+28^2+8^2+35^2 = 41\times 53$, etc...